# Backup to a remote Encrypted APFS drive mounted through Samba. Is this a sound plan?

Tags: encryption, aes, macos, end-to-end-encryption, samba

Say I have a remote machine (something like a VPS) that I have no physical access or physical authority over other than a user on it (with root access). However, I'd like to do Time Machine backups on it.

Time Machine is a mac tool for incremental backups.

Now I understand that Samba isn't secure, but hear me out. The security I'm thinking about isn't hinged on Samba protocol and I don't need to expose it publicly.

So what I'm planning to do is:

- Create a docker container with Samba service exposed from it
- From that samba drive expose an encrypted APFS image file
- Tunnel to that server with ssh (or VPN)
- Use that tunnel to mount that samba drive, then mount that APFS image, then let Time Machine do its backup.

Currently I have this setup in my home network and it works fine. But I'm wondering how secure it's when done remotely.

**The question:** Given that I don't own the VPS, can an eavesdropper with root access to the VPS listen on the connection and read plaintext data going to the image when backups happen?

Basically this question can be reduced to: "Is the encrypted APFS mounting 100% client-side, in such a way where all the communication between the client and the image is encrypted?"

Comment: "Now I understand that Samba isn't secure, but hear me out". What concerns do you have with the SMB protocol? Last I checked, it does offer authentication and encryption. Or are you concerned about the Samba codebase itself?

Comment: @multithr3at3d Well, there has been way too many hacks based on samba... last I heard was wannacry ransomware. My understanding is samba isn't to be trusted publicly but is OK for a local setup.